# $ab+ac+bc=2\quad ,\quad\min(10a^2+10b^2+c^2)=?$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

> If $ab+ac+bc=2$, find minimum value of $10a^2+10b^2+c^2$
>
> $1)3\qquad\qquad2)4\qquad\qquad3)8\qquad\qquad4)10$

I used AM-GM inequality for three variables:
$$ab+ac+bc\ge3(abc)^{\frac23}\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2\ge3(abc)^{\frac23}$$
$$10a^2+10b^2+c^2\ge 3(10abc)^{\frac23}$$
Hence $10a^2+b^2+c^2\ge2\times 10^{\frac23}$. But it is not in the options.

Comment: The shift $a \to \frac{a}{\sqrt 2},b \to \frac{b}{\sqrt 2}, c \to \frac{c}{\sqrt 2}$ changes this to the duplicate problem. In any case, Michael Rozenberg's approach is quite flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$10a^2+10b^2+c^2-4(ab+bc+ca)=\frac{2}{5}(5a-b-c)^2+\frac{3}{5}(4b-c)^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you please explain what is the mistake in my approach? And how did you realize that the RHS can be written in this form ? It would be really hard for me to recognize it.

Comment: The mistake is that your use of the AM-GM inequality does not satisfy the equality case. To find the equality case, assume by the asymmetric form of the expression that a=b and solve a two-variable equation to find equality occurs when a=b=c/4. Once you know the equality case, it's easy to factor the expression as a sum of squares.